# save,progress,DDD,Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity, save, progress

I'm new to Domain driven design. I have a web application where user would be able to save intermediate results of progress through a task i.e. saving as data on a form as draft and coming back to fill it later. If the form represents an entity and its the root of the aggregates, is it ok to save the entity in half-baked state based on status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, there really is no correct general answer to this.

While one can go this route it could interfere with another principle I tend to follow which is that no Domain Object can be in an invalid state.

Since the Domain of your subsystem is a submission of a form though it might be logical to do this by state - that is the domain itself does not exclude half filled in forms, only on submission does the rule that all mandatory fields need to be completed really comes into affect.

For example it might make alot of sense for a half filled in form to be valid - especially if the form needs to go through a workflow (such as get supervisor signoff) till it could be counted as being complete

Comment: Thank you so much saret. Yes, it is context based. This is the same conflict I'm facing with Domain Object not being in valid state and should I allow it to be save as it progresses through the workflow.

Comment: My pleasure - seems like in this case it's ok - you really have two different types of validation - ValidForSave and ValidForSubmission

Comment: @GeorgeKT Perhaps the issue is that you are trying to model two different concepts with a single domain entity? I am quite new to DDD and trying to learn as well, however I feel like saving progression could be part of the domain if seen as a business concern. How about having a DraftEntity which is allowed to be incomplete. The DraftEntity would then be turned into Entity once the process is completed.

Comment: As @plalx wrote, we have to design model with fact : you need 2 different Entity and use them each other when needed. The draft status etc is the idea to represent the fact we need a partial Entity, nammed as DraftEntity, acting without business rules application or for example, one rule, like checking Unique rules to indicate to your user something about that. And that, it is really decoupled, it is DDD oriented.